# Nuget project class library

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.
When I want to publish a Nuget package, I can only do it with a .Net Standard class library project. I can't do this with .Net Framework class library project. perhaps I'm missing a dependance but I don't know which one.
If you could help me.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, I found the solution.
In fact it is necessary to do this:

1. create a .Net project Standard class library,
2. close the project,
3. go into the .csproj file and replace the item `<TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>`
   by the element `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`
4. reopen the project and we should be able to publish its class library

link : [How do I create a Nuget package with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656655/how-do-i-create-a-nuget-package-with-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.