# Creating nuget package for .net framework library

Tags: nuget, .net-framework-version

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community edition V15.2 (.net 4.6). 
I have a .Net framework class library, which refer Akka.net nuget package.
I want to publish my assembly as a nuget package. But the package option is missing in Visual Studio

NB: I tried to convert it to a .NET standard library as specified in following link ([Nuget project class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425145/nuget-project-class-library))
But it did not worked for me.
How can I publish my .net framework library using Nuget

Comment: Have you read this[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2015)?

Answer (score 2):

- Go to https://www.nuget.org/downloads download nuget.exe
- Use the command: nuget.exe pack "C:\yourproject.csproj"

Examples of the pack command:

nuget pack

nuget pack foo.nuspec

nuget pack foo.csproj

nuget pack foo.csproj -Build -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Release

nuget pack foo.nuspec -Version 2.1.0

Comment: Nicholas, your answer triggered a low quality flag in the system