# Including Text Template (*.tt) into the .NET Standard NuGet Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard, csproj

I publish a .NET Standard class library as a package on MyGet feed by selecting “Generate NuGet Package on Build” in project settings and using MyGet building service. My `Cds.IoC.csprj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Cds.IoC</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Authors>...</Authors>
    <Company>...</Company>
    <Product>...</Product>
    <Description>...</Description>
    <Copyright>© 2018</Copyright>
    <PackageTags>...</PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>...</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <AssemblyVersion>0.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>0.0.0.1</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.1-alpha</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I add a Text Template `Some.tt` file to the package, so it will show up in the referencing project? I would not like it to generate output on package build; just looking for a way to automatically add the TT file to the referencing project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add additional files to a nuget package in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498659/how-do-you-add-additional-files-to-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add a Text Template Some.tt file to the package, so it will show up in the referencing project?

You can use the property `<Pack>true</Pack>` to add the Text Template Some.tt file to the package:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Cds.IoC</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Authors>...</Authors>
    <Company>...</Company>
    <Product>...</Product>
    <Description>...</Description>
    <Copyright>© 2018</Copyright>
    <PackageTags>...</PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>...</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <AssemblyVersion>0.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>0.0.0.1</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.1-alpha</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="some.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>some.txt</LastGenOutput>    
    </None>
    <None Update="some.txt">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>some.tt</DependentUpon>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When you build the project, the generated source file `some.tt` will added to the nuget package, then you add this nuget package to the project, this file will added to the project.

Check the document [NuGet pack and restore as MSBuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The example is wrong though. The only thing needed to deliver tt as it is to the referencing project is `<ItemGroup><None Update="some.tt"><Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator><Pack>True</Pack></None></ItemGroup>`