# Copy files into project on NuGet package install

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I am creating a project (backend) which is distributed as a NuGet package.
The package should add files (js, css, vue, json,...) to the consuming project on installation.
This is necessary because the consuming project should be able to work with the files directly.

Both projects are **.NET Core** (`.csproj`).

I tried the following:

1. Add files via `content` and `contentFiles` to the package.
2. Add an `init.ps1` and `install.ps1` file to the tools folder in the package.

None of the above works.

What's the preferred way to add these files to the project?
Is it even possible by installing a NuGet package?

I have [seen](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v8/contrib/build/NuSpecs/tools/install.ps1) that it works in the *Umbraco CMS* via `install.ps1` but that's .NET Framework.

---

Edit: I have tried it now with a *.targets file.

This is the NuGet package content:

[image] (Inspired by the RavenDB.Embedded package)

Problem here is this will only link to the files in the project but not actually copy them to the project on disk.

The generated .nuspec file contains the following items:

```
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/Resources/Countries/countries.de-de.json" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="any/any/Resources/Countries/countries.en-us.json" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="any/any/Resources/Localization/zero.en-us.json" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
```

Consuming solution:

[image]

---

Edit 2: I want to reach this goal:

(Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924129/copy-files-from-nuget-package-to-output-directory-with-msbuild-in-csproj-and-do) where `install.ps1` was used)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "should add files"? Should they be copied to output folder on build or added to the solution as source files?

Comment: @thatguy they should be added to the solution as content files on package installation.

Comment: That is possible with `contentFiles`. Do you mind showing your attempt, so we can identify what might be going wrong?

Comment: @thatguy Thanks. I have included an update in the description. As you can see files are added to the project now, but only linked and not copied.

Comment: The behavior of `contentFiles` is to be added as link to the corresponding project and optionally being copied to the output directory. They are *immutable* by definition. Apart from that, you are able to work with them. If the problem is that they cannot be *modified*, `contentFiles` cannot do that.

Comment: @thatguy And which command or whatever can copy my files into the project on package installation if not `contentFiles`? Can I solve this issue with the `.targets` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219268/discussion-between-thatguy-and-tobi-at).

Comment: @tobi.at Did you get this question answered via chat?

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete sadly not, no.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the meantime? I have a similar case, where I want to package up a .NET (Core/6) project into NuGet, but one that also includes JS files (for Gulp) that should be possible to reference from the consuming project's Node modules (and also a package.json for NPM): https://github.com/Lombiq/Open-Source-Orchard-Core-Extensions/issues/23#issuecomment-1030951912

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to copy the file to project only during installation.

Comment: @VolodymyrLiashenko I've the same problem and try to copy XSD-Files. I also want to copy the exact same file from nuget to multiple different locations of that project. Are there any solutions to that problem?

Comment: This is how we solved this: https://orcharddojo.net/blog/delivering-a-node-js-asset-pipeline-as-a-nuget-package