# How to add additional files to a nuget package and reference those files within the nuget package code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, dotnet-cli

I'm wanting to provide some additional files in a `nuget` package so that whenever and wherever it is installed, the files are provided and in the correct location.

The problem I'm having is that I have code that needs to reference these files in order to run.

The files are 3 `.exe` files and a `.jar` file in a single directory...

[image]

This is the code that references that folder location...

```cs
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\WebDrivers\\Drivers\\";
```

I want to be able to package this code and the files up so that whenever this nuget package is installed, this code will point to a valid location.

How do I do this?

First thing I tried was to add the following to the `.csproj` file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="WebDrivers\Drivers\chromedriver.exe">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="WebDrivers\Drivers\geckodriver.exe">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="WebDrivers\Drivers\msedgedriver.exe">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="WebDrivers\Drivers\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.0.jar">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

This only works if you reference the project in the same solution. It doesn't work after you have done a `dotnet pack` and installed the package in a different project/solution.

Second thing I tried was the accepted answer here...

[Copy files from Nuget package to output directory with MsBuild in .csproj and dotnet pack command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924129/copy-files-from-nuget-package-to-output-directory-with-msbuild-in-csproj-and-do)

But I couldn't get any files to copy...

[image]

**SASelenium.Framework.csproj**

```xml
  <ItemGroup Label="FilesToCopy">
    <Content Include="SASelenium.Framework.targets" PackagePath="build/SASelenium.Framework.targets" />
    <Content Include="LogFiles\*.config" Pack="true" PackagePath="contentFiles\LogFiles">
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**SASelenium.Framework.targets**

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <LogFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\contentFiles\LogFiles\*.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CopyLogFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(LogFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)CopiedLogFiles\" />
</Target>
```

I don't see any files when I build the project where this package is installed.

Even if this did work, how would I ensure the code within the package is always pointing at these files when running from any project?

Comment: _But I couldn't get any files to copy..._ Targets from different question are used for `*.config` files. Did you try to look at the file extensions before copy-pasting? Where are your `*.config` files?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski They are shown in the screenshot. I have a `test.config` in a `LogFiles` directory

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by updating my `.csproj` to the following for each required file...

```xml
<Content Include="WebDrivers\Drivers\chromedriver.exe">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
  <pack>true</pack>
</Content>
```

After a `dotnet pack` I was able to see the files by inspecting package

[image]

After adding the nuget package to a new project and building the solution I was able to see the files in the `bin` folder...

[image]

Which means the code to find the file folder based on the currently executing assembly works as hoped.