# .NET core 2.1 Custom Nuget package. Problem with missing *.runtimeconfig.json file in the project where the package was installed

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a console app project (.net core 2.1) which is my "custom package".
The output of the package is the * .dll file.

I have installed my own package on different projects.

after

```
dotnet publish
```

I see that *.dll (from the package) file in the publish folder.

When I am trying to run this dll.
I have an error like this:

> Cannot use file stream for [D:\Daily\Daily*.deps.json]: No such file or directory
> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\Daily\Daily'. Failed to run as a self-contained app. - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'D:\Daily\Daily*.runtimeconfig.json' was not found. - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'D:\Daily\Daily*.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.

I spend some time to search a solution for my case but I can not fix it with possible solutions which I found.

When I did

```
dotnet publish
```

on the Package Project in outputs I see all what I need.

Problems occurs when package is installed in different project.

I tried to use

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

My nuspec file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ProjectName</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>ProjectName</title>
    <authors></authors>
    <owners></owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description></description>
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2021</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.1">
            some dependencies
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <summary>ProjectName package</summary>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\ProjectName\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\ProjectName.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\" /> 
    <file src="..\ProjectName\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\ProjectName.deps.json" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\" />   
    <file src="..\ProjectName\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\ProjectName.runtimeconfig.json" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\" />  
    <file src="..\ProjectName\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\ProjectName.runtimeconfig.dev.json" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1\" />  
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This is how i solved it.

I created a ProjectName.targets file in the project generating nuget package.
[Snapshot of nupkg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAjRs.png)

Included this property in the project using this nuget package

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

These links were helpful
[Copy files from Nuget package to output directory with MsBuild in .csproj and dotnet pack command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924129/copy-files-from-nuget-package-to-output-directory-with-msbuild-in-csproj-and-do)

[Automatic native and managed DLLs extracting from Nuget Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104838/automatic-native-and-managed-dlls-extracting-from-nuget-package/40652794#40652794)