# Nuget package `contentFiles` are not getting copied into the project

Tags: c#, nuget, nuspec

I have a Nuget package that generated by  `msbuild.exe -t:"Pack"` command. From the **NUSPEC** file looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>LibraryId</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Developer</authors>
    <owners>Company</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <repository type="git" url="https://github.com/cilerler/fake.git" />
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.ClearScript" version="6.0.2" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="3.1.5" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="3.1.5" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="3.1.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="Microsoft.CSharp" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="mscorlib" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Core" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Net.Http" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Numerics" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml.Linq" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/net48/MyFile.txt" buildAction="Content" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When I add the package into a **plain** .NetFramework4.8 Console app, `MyFile.txt` does not show up in the tree, and it doesn't get copied into the `bin/Debug` folder.

Any idea what it might be?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content files are only supported in NuGet 4.0+ and only when using **PackageReference** in your project. However, the reason that they are not copied to the output folder is that this is the default option. If you want them to be copied, you have to specify it explicitly with `copyToOutput="true"` in the `files` tag like this:

`<files include="any/net48/MyFile.txt" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true"/>`

Comment: Thank you, I generate it via `msbuild.exe -t:"Pack"` any idea how may I add it as a parameter, so it can be passed correctly?

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212132/439130  Thanks again