# JSON files cannot be found inside my Nuget Package

Tags: json, vb.net, nuget

I have a vb.net project that reads from multiple JSON files during execution. When I create a NuGet package of this project and try to use the package in a test solution, I get an exception saying that the JSON file could not be found. In the exception message (I'll attach it below), it shows that the program is looking at the file location of the test solution. Ideally, I want the JSON file to "live" inside of the NuGet package so the path to the file is constant.

The stranger thing about this issue is that I pushed a package the same way, using the JSON files, about a year ago and had no issues then. I only have a couple of years of experience so forgive me if my explanation of this issue isn't clear.

Inside the package solution, I'm using `IO.File.ReadAllText(filename)` to access the JSON file. Could this be problematic when using the package as a reference in other solutions?

[Example of the Solution looking for the JSON file in the Test Solution, not inside the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky854.png)

In the package solution, I've set all the JSON to `Copy Always` for the `Copy To Output Directory` field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073501/how-do-you-set-nuget-contentfiles-copytooutput-to-true-when-using-a-net-standar

Comment: @CodeCaster , this seems to work for a C# project , but mine is a vb.net project. I dont think the PackageCopyToOutput is an option in VB

Comment: Or you know, try it. The project file format is the same.

Comment: Tried with no success

Comment: I think, based on the MSBuild docs, it writes the nuspec file it uses to build the package.  Have you tried looking for that?