# Project that's a NuGet package which copies its own build output into consumers' build output

Tags: c#, nuget, csproj

I have an SDK-style project (producing a console application) that I'd like to pack into a NuGet package. This project is a *runtime* tool, so its build output (the console application) needs to be present in the build output directory of other projects which reference the NuGet package.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

---

It looks like [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212132/3063273) is the idiomatic way to get the first project's *content* into the consuming project's build output:

```xml
<Content Include="...">
    <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
</Content>
```

But I don't want my console application's project's *content* to be copied... instead I want *the console application itself* to appear in the build output of consumers.

---

It looks like I might be able to hand-craft a .nuspec file with [`<contentFiles>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#contentfiles), but I'd like to avoid doing that because it makes certain things more difficult in the CI/CD pipeline.